# Trouble selecting an item in a SELECT box with jQuery with a quot

Tags: jquery, character, drop-down-menu

I am having a hidden form with a list which I need to select an option from when a user wants to view this form.
I was using
var assignee = 'persons name';

jQuery('#edit-form' option[value='+option+']:first').attr("selected", "selected");

I tried doing this, but this is not working as the value in the option tag is not specified with the \ as well, so it won't find a match

```
jQuery('#edit-form option[value='+option.replace(/\'/,'\\\'')+']:first').attr("selected", "selected");
```

So is doing it this way the following my only option ?

```
jQuery('#edit-form option').each(function(){
  if(jQuery(this).val() == option) {        
   jQuery(this).attr("selected", "selected");
   return false;
     }
});
```

a Test page

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  //test vars
  var option1 = "option two";
  var option2 = "option '";
  var option = option2;

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#edit-form [name=select1] option').each(function(){
      if($(this).val() == option) {        
    $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
    return false;
       }
    });

    $('#edit-form [name=select2] option[value='+option+']:first').attr("selected", "selected");
    option = option.replace(/\'/,'\\\'');
    $('#edit-form [name=select3] option[value='+option+']:first').attr("selected", "selected");
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="edit-form">
  <select name=select1>
  <option value="option one">option one</option>
  <option value="option two">option two</option>
  <option value="option two">option two</option>
  <option value="option \'">option \'</option>
  <option value="option '">option '</option>
  </select>
  <select name=select2>
  <option value="option one">option one</option>
  <option value="option two">option two</option>
  <option value="option two">option two</option>
  <option value="option \'">option \'</option>
  <option value="option '">option '</option>
  </select>  
  <select name=select3>
  <option value="option one">option one</option>
  <option value="option two">option two</option>
  <option value="option two">option two</option>
  <option value="option \'">option \'</option>
  <option value="option '">option '</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
jQuery('#edit-form option[value="'+option+'"]:first').attr("selected", "selected");
```

Note the use of the `"` and `'` characters.

E.g. These are all valid strings:

```
"Valid 'string'"
'valid "string"'
// also valid with escape chars
"valid \"string"
'valid \'string'
```

but not these

```
"not valid "string""
'not valid 'string''
```

You can also see this with the syntax highlighter.

**Edit:**

Works for me if I use this:

```
$('#edit-form select[name="select3"] option[value="'+option+'"]').first().attr("selected", "selected");
```

Note: I use `.first()` instead of `:first` and proper `select[name="select3"]`. Make sure that you use proper jQuery selectors.

Comment: Thanks but if you'd have tried with the example page you would have seen that isn't working either.

Comment: Alright, that indeed did make it work! Thanks for that, jQuery acting weird at times I see.